# SonarQube - is Condition coverage actually the branch coverage?

Tags: sonarqube, metrics

SonarQube describes the "Condition" coverage like this:

On each line of code containing some boolean expressions, the condition coverage simply answers the following question: 'Has each boolean expression been evaluated both to true and false?'. This is the density of possible branches in flow control structures that have been followed during unit tests execution.

[http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Metric+definitions](https://web.archive.org/web/20150511080456/http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metric+definitions)

Well but I suspect they mean "branch coverage":

if (A || B || C)

Testing A=true and B=true yields 100%, without the need of checking the last expression (C). Also just two branches are tested - true and false for the whole expression, not individual expressions. Is that right?

As far as I know, condition coverage should check all conditions in an expression.

Answer (score 4):

You can read the following thread of discussion: http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/I-can-t-understand-the-meaning-of-quot-condition-coverage-quot-in-SonarQube-tt5029339.html

Comment: Well they say the same but I do not understand their arguments. If a condition has n expression (if A || B || C || D) then there are still only two branches (true and false outcome) and you would need just two test cases.

Comment: That's why I think it's more branch coverage than condition coverage. In this thread, I asked SonarSource why they changed the label but they haven't replied yet.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I misread that. But I remember you were shown 0/4 for (X && Y), which would not make sense. For branch coverage, it should be 0/2 with no test. Condition coverage test cases can be calculated: 2^N where N means components of a compbound condition.

Comment: if (A | B) => 2 branches, true or false. But || or && operators increase the number of branches. Indeed the second operand may or may not be evaluated.

Comment: I do not think so. The result of the compbound condition will always be true or false, regardless how many operators there are because there are only two branches of the code - IF and ELSE, no other branches. If you look at the control flow graph, there are two edges.

Comment: Nope. Let's take the following example: function f() { if (A || B) {...} else {...}}. The cyclomatic complexity (number of branches) is 3, not 2. If condition A is true, condition B won't be executed. If condition A is false, condition B will be executed. Then the overall condition is either true or false.

Comment: Not really, cyclomatic complexity determines PATHS, not branches. Branches are always (control flow graph ca show that well) just 2 from an IF statement. Paths are combinations between nodes.

Answer (score 3):

For me on SonarQube 5.6 ***condition coverage* is really the same as *path coverage*** as defined e.g. here: http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2007/03/02/statement-branch-and-path-coverage-testing-in-java.html?page=2

For example, my test report points out that on an if-condition that checks two boolean flags, it insists that all 4 possible combinations have to be checked before 100% coverage is attained.